# pentaho spoon transformation to delete data from table

Tags: pentaho, jobs, delete-row

I'm trying to write a ETL job using pentaho data integration tool, in spoon. Used "delete" icon and provided the target tabl details but the rows are not getting deleted.and no error. I have access to the schema.Please suggest.

Comment: The delete step must be "primed". Rows must flow into to provide keys to delete by. If this is what you have, please post a screenshot of your transformation, and provide details for the steps used.

Comment: actually i tried to post a screenshot but not able to do so. i have mentuioned all the field names in the look up column

Comment: In my transformation,i mentioned the Delete step alone and gave the schema name and target table details in the delete step

Comment: You Can use execute SQL Script and write delete query in it.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use the "Delete" step first you need to have a data source where PDI will read the keys to look for in the table. So, your transformation should look like this:

[image]

In my example, the first step queries the origin table for a list of Ids to be deleted, and then passes them to the Delete step as keys to be used as condition for the delete instruction.